# Emotion detection: neural network overfitting on audio files

Tags: python, overfitting, tensorflow, keras

I am working on an analysis of audio data to understand emotions using the [RAVDESS dataset](https://smartlaboratory.org/ravdess/).

The input is the Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients (MFCCs) of each audio file, extracted using a Python module called [Librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/).

The output expected is a prediction of one out of 8 classes (happy, angry, neutral and so on).

Actually, the accuracy of the model is 83% on the training set and 69 % on the test set.

To review the project completely, in [this](https://github.com/marcogdepinto/Emotion-Classification-Ravdess) Github repository you will find the previous version.

**Issue**: looking at the plot of my cost function, it seems that the model starts to overfit after epoch 300 (training is decreasing way faster that test)

[image: Loss Function]

I am searching for a strategy to improve the performances of the model: the goal is to reach 80% on the test set.

---

**General info about the problem and the data**

The shape of the training set and the test set are:

```
((1642, 40, 1), (810, 40, 1))
```

How the neural network is build:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(256, 5,padding='same',
                     input_shape=(40,1)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(8)))
    model.add(Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same',))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same',))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(10))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.00001, decay=1e-6)

    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])

    cnnhistory=model.fit(x_traincnn, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=500, validation_data=(x_testcnn, y_test))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, 40 dimensions for one sample, but you are creating 256 possible filters for your first layer!

Also you have 1600 samples to train a model that has several thousand parameters. This is too much!

Two things to try:

- something else than a neural network, as less than 2000 samples is ridiculous for any deep network
- try 2 layers, at most, with perhaps 10 filters for the C layer, and your 10 outputs

I don't think that anything more complicated will be trainable with the data you have.

Comment: I will try to make some changes according to your suggestions: thank you so much for your feedback!